# VHDL - Index out range even If I made concurrent checking using when-else

Tags: logic, vhdl, cpu-registers

I'm implementing a register file where I wanna read asynchronously and write on the rising edge.

I made concurrent checks on the addresses and the writing occurs inside a process.

However, it always cause me a fatal error and I don't know why!

Here's my code if anyone could help and tell me how can I read asynchronously and write on rising edge

Thank you!

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity RegFile is
  port(
            outData1    : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            outData2    : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            inData      : in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            writeEn     : in  std_logic;
            reg1Sel     : in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
            reg2Sel     : in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
            writeRegSel : in  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
            clk         : in  std_logic
    );
  end RegFile;


architecture Register_File of RegFile is

type registerFile is array(0 to 5) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal registers : registerFile;
signal reg1Address,reg2Address : integer;
signal reg1FinalAddressing,reg2FinalAddressing : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);


begin

--Conversion of logic vector to unsigned integer
reg1Address <= to_integer(unsigned(reg1Sel));
reg2Address <= to_integer(unsigned(reg2Sel));

reg1FinalAddressing <= reg1Sel when (reg1Address<6 ) else 
                                    (others => '0');

reg2FinalAddressing <= reg2Sel when (reg2Address<6 ) else 
                                    (others => '0');


outData1 <= registers(to_integer(unsigned(reg1FinalAddressing)));
outData2 <= registers(to_integer(unsigned(reg2FinalAddressing)));


process (clk) is
begin
    -- Reading from Registers 1 and 2
    if rising_edge(clk) then
                -- Writing to Register file Case Enabled
                if writeEn = '1' then
                    registers(to_integer(unsigned(writeRegSel))) <= inData;
                    -- Case a value being written to register file, it will be out simultaneously if
                    -- the register was already selected. (The updated values are being released instantly).
                    if reg1Sel = writeRegSel then
                        outData1 <= inData;
                    end if;
                    if reg2Sel = writeRegSel then
                        outData2 <= inData;
                    end if;
                end if;

    end if;

end process;
end Register_File;
```

Comment: Can you provide the means to duplicate your error? (A [mcve], the actual error message is helpful as well.) Note you're not clamping WriteRegSel to the index range of registers and it can have a value of "110" and "111" (6 and 7). `if writeEn = '1' and unsigned(WriteRegSel) < 6 then` (don't write out of bounds).

Comment: You have a multiple drive problem. You're assigning `outData1` and `outData2` both directly and in the unlabeled process. That doesn't work. Realize signals are wires: if you connect two powers sources in different states together with a wire and they will short-circuit. That could potentially happen in an FPGA, potentially even causing damage. Therefore the synthesis tool prevents you from making that mistake: you're only allowed to assign a signal from one source.

Comment: The multiple drivers can be cured by moving the assignments to the process (outside the if statement inferring a register). Add `reg1FinalAddressing` and `reg2FinalAddressing` to the process sensitivity list. Please clarify your problem (the actual fatal error message). It's not illegal to have multiple drivers the element type for outData1 an Outdata2 have a resolved element type. An FPGA synthesis tool will consider it an error. We can't tell what your error is without the error message or the means to replicate the problem.

Comment: @user1155120 I thing the error is in the title. "Index it of range".

Comment: Which index? there are three.

Comment: @user1155120 probably `writeRegSel`, as there is no check on that ;p